Even Black Square Chessboard Rooks
I'm stuck on this problem:
"There are $8$ rooks on the chessboard such that no two of them they don't hit each other. Prove that the black squares contain an even number of rooks."
What I've tried:
I first realized that proving for black or white squares is the same thing, because if you have even white, you must have even black.
I noticed that when you pick a square for a rook, you can't place any other rook on the same row or column similar to sudoku with numbers. I imagined that when a rook is placed, the row and column gets cut and removed and combining the separated rows/columns to create a square 1 size smaller.
I put the first rook on the first column.
I started looking at smaller cases like a $2\times2$, in the first row no matter what square you pick, you will be left with a $1\times1$ with the same colour (because the adjacent squares have opposite colours and diagonal have the same). So $2\times2$ works.
I tried extending it to $3\times3$, if you place a rook on any of the corners, it will turn into a $2\times2$ again, so I hypothesised $n\times n$, when $n$ is odd will result in odd number of black or white squares (depending which one has $5$ and the other $4$ in the $3\times3$) and even $n$ will result in even black and white.
Now when I put a rook in the outer edge of the $3\times3$, I get a $2\times2$ but with the rows of same colour, this gives the same result.
Now I tried a $4\times4$, putting a rook in the corners will turn into a $3\times3$, let's say WLOG black was on top left corner, now it will become a $3\times3$ with $5$ blacks, meaning there will be an odd number of black, and we will have $1$+odd which will be even.
Now I want to do the same process with a $4\times4$ and larger squares, but there are too many cases especially putting the first rook in squares that are not corners, because then you will get weird colour configurations.
Also I think my overall process is not the "proper" way of doing it and would love to know how to tackle problems like these.

As mention by HackR, this question is similar to parity of rooks
Maybe this explanation is more simple :

We have a number for each column (c=1 to 8); a number for each row (r=1 to 8). We can previously rotate the chessboard, so that the first cell (1,1) is white.
We define a value for each cell $(r,c)$ : $v=r+c$ ; So all white cells have a value which is an even-number, and all black cells have a value which is an odd-number.
If we put the rooks so that 2 of them cannot hit each other, we are sure that we have one rook in each column, and one in each row. So, if we compute sum of values of the 8 cells where we have a rook, we obtain $2*(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8)$.
This number is even.
When we compute sum of integers, the sum is even only when the number of odd-integers is an even-number. So to obtain a total which is even, we need to select an even-number of black cells (=cells with odd value).

